# Dart2js brackets Symbol in metadata annotation

Tags: dart, dart2js

I can run this code on Dart VM:

```dart
@MirrorsUsed(metaTargets: Tag)
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Tag {
  final Symbol name;
  const Tag(this.name);
}
@proxy
@Tag(#[])
class Tagged {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(this);
    ClassMirror classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
    classMirror.metadata.forEach((em) {
      if (em.reflectee is Tag && em.reflectee.name == invocation.memberName)
         print(invocation.positionalArguments);
    });
  }
}
void main() {
  var tagged = new Tagged();
  tagged[42];
  tagged.foo();
  tagged["Dart"];
}
```

output:

> [42]
>   [Dart]

But when i try to compile it with dart2js it fails with this error:

> [Error from Dart2JS]:
>   bin\dart2jswithbracketanotation.dart:9:7:
>   Expected identifier, but got '['.
>   @Tag(#[])

So which one has the bug?:

1. (Dart VM) because I can run it at all.
2. (dart2js) because it doesn't compile to js.

**update:**  [I reported this bug](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19305&thanks=19305&ts=1402246767)

Comment: What should `#[]` do/produce?

Comment: According to the spec it should create a symbol for the `[]` operator. What error do you get if you use `const Symbol('[]');` instead (should have the same semantic)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i added a bit more boilerplate - for realism :)

Comment: Have you already tried `const Symbol('[]');` or some other operator like `#+`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes. It's ok with `#+` but not `#[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Dart2JS because an operator should be allowed at this position.

Comment: Can you fill a bug report?  I just want to know on which behavior i can rely.

Comment: Why don't you create the bug report yourself?

Comment: Can you provide me with the link where it says that it should create a symbol for the [] operator? I'm still not sure which one(VM or dart2js) has a bug.

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.qke6yiz8c62q section 'Symbols' symbolLiteral: `'#'(operator | (identifier ('.' identifier)*))`

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right. Besides, it works for other operators. I will report this issue.